# Integrate react-native version 0.62.2 into existing IOs app error

Tags: ios, react-native, nodes, node-modules

Following react-native document to integrate react-native to existing IOs app. The structure of directory as document to integrate is

```
android/
ios/
   Podfile
   #...other ios file
node_modules/
  react-native
  react
  @react-native-community  
package.json
....
```

So that when run pod install from Podfile can call function use_native_modules

```
require_relative './libs/react-native-libs/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
...
use_native_modules!
```

## But I want to organize the project different due to not change my existing project structure,

so I add react-native-integrate module like as a part of my IOs project like this

```
my_ios_project
  Podfile
  libs/
     ... other modules
     react-native-integrate
         node_modules
             react-native
             @react-native-community
             react 
         package.json
```

And then I change the path of relative-module:

```
require_relative './libs/react-native-libs/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
...
use_native_module!
```

But the problem is in native_modules files and others libraries in node_modules use absolute `require`. For example in `@react-community/cli-platform-ios/native_module.rb`  there is a line such as

```
cli_resolve_script = "try {console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);} catch (e) {console.log(require('@react-native/cli'))}"
```

that require absolute path '@react-native-community'. So that when I run `Pod install` my pod file from parent directory the `node` can not recognize my children module so that it cause error.
[image]

As I know the node_module 'spaths list is basically a list of node_modules directories under every directory from the current directory to the root directory. And the current directory is that the directory of the Podfile that call require 'native_module.rb'
Could you please give me a solution solve this problem like add node path from children directory or something else ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

- add package.json file at root ios with property `main`
- add react-native.config.js at root ios project, edit path to `cli-platform-ios` and `cli-platform-android`:

```
'use strict';

const ios = require('./node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios');
const android = require('./node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android');

module.exports = {
  commands: [...ios.commands, ...android.commands],
  platforms: {
    ios: {
      linkConfig: ios.linkConfig,
      projectConfig: ios.projectConfig,
      dependencyConfig: ios.dependencyConfig,
    },
    android: {
      linkConfig: android.linkConfig,
      projectConfig: android.projectConfig,
      dependencyConfig: android.dependencyConfig,
    },
  }
};
```

- Run `pod install` again

**Checkout my demo here:** 
https://github.com/lehoangnam97/demo-intergrate-rn-on-ios